# Passing a Method with return value type in a for loop

Tags: c#

Ok, guys i am a little confused about this thing. I will show you the code i have issues with.

So i have a CellMap class which has this method:

```
public Vector3 GetFreeCell()
{
    Vector3 result = new Vector3();

    if (mOccupiedPoint != null)
    {
        result = (Vector3)mOccupiedPoint[0];

        mOccupiedPoint.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Next i have my WorldMap class which has this method:

```
private void AddObject(GameObjectBase obj, int times, Vector3 position)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        Vector3 tempPos = position;

        AddObject(obj, tempPos);
    }
}
```

So now when i pass for a Vector3 parameter GetFreeCell() in my AddObject method like this:

```
private CellMap mCellMap;

public WorldMap()
{
    CreateCellMap(100, 1, 100);

    AddObject(new DarkForestTreeA(), 1000, mCellMap.GetFreeCell());

}
```

i get the same old Vector3 value from the mCellMap.GetFreeCell().I can change the AddObject() method like:

```
private void AddObject(GameObjectBase obj, int times)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {

        AddObject(obj, mCellMap.GetFreeCell());
    }
}
```

but i want to keep the Vector3 parameter.
Can somebody help me out and give me a hint how can make the GetFreeCell() method execute in the for loop, but to pass it only as a parameter?

Comment: Deleting from the front of a `List` is inefficient, consider using a queue or linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but if I understand what you're asking, you want to pass a function (in this case `GetFreeCell`) to `AddObject` which will be invoked `times` many times. In that case, use a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx):

```
public WorldMap()
{
    CreateCellMap(100, 1, 100);

    AddObject(new DarkForestTreeA(), 1000, mCellMap.GetFreeCell); // note no () after method name
}

private void AddObject(GameObjectBase obj, int times, Func<Vector3> vectorFunc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        AddObject(obj, vectorFunc());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i was looking for, but it seems i wanted it a little bit simpler than passing a delegate..i thought there is some way to pass it just as a Vector3...

Comment: @MamaTate If you pass a `Vector3` it will be the same `Vector3` every time through the loop. If you want a different `Vector3` each time you iterate through your `for`-loop, you'll have to do something different. A delegate is probably the cleanest solution.

Comment: Sounds like a tautology: _"if I understand what you're asking, you want to pass a delegate... In that case, use a delegate"_ ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter yep. I was getting ahead of myself.

Comment: Yeah thanks my problem was that i didn't knew what i was looking for and so i got down voted :) Next time i will try to get my question right :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
private void AddObject(GameObjectBase obj, int times, Vector3 position)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        Vector3 tempPos = mCellMap.GetFreeCell();

        AddObject(obj, tempPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass in an object and have it just update itself for each use.

You can pass a function into the method, and use that to get a position for each iteration:

```
private void AddObject(GameObjectBase obj, int times, Func<Vector3> getPosition)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        Vector3 tempPos = getPosition();

        AddObject(obj, tempPos);
    }
}
```

You Can call it using a lambda expression for the function:

```
AddObject(new DarkForestTreeA(), 1000, () => mCellMap.GetFreeCell());
```

---

A solution that is a bit more tricky, is to send in a "magic" object, that will convert itself to a `Vector3` when used, and return a new value each time:

```
public class MagicVector3 {

  private Func<Vector3> _getVector;

  public MagicVector3(Func<Vector3> getVector) {
    _getVector = getVector;
  }

  public static implicit operator Vector3(MagicVector3 magic) {
    return magic._getVector();
  }

}
```

Now you can just change the `Vector3` parameter to `MagicVector3`, and call it using:

```
AddObject(new DarkForestTreeA(), 1000, new MagicVector3(() => mCellMap.GetFreeCell()));
```

This code has a bit of a code smell, though. Normally you wouldn't use a value like that, as it kind of hides what's actually happening.

Comment: Why use a lambda when you can use a method group?

Comment: @Magus: Good point. That would work just fine, I just didn't think of it.